# CSS triangle side with round on left? PART 2

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is what it should look like:
[image: align top]
<sub>(source: [kerrydeaf.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140404095357/http://www.kerrydeaf.com/arrow.png))</sub>

```
span.trig_italic2{color:#000000; line-height:17px;font-size:12px;font-family:opensansitalic;     
width: 100px;
height: 36px;
background: #FFCC05;
position: relative;
-moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
margin-right:50px;
padding:3px 4px 3px 4px;}
span.trig_italic2:before
{
content:"";
display:block;
position: absolute;
right: -22.5px;
top:0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 11px solid transparent;
border-color: transparent transparent #FFCC05 #FFCC05;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/alma/zQKhb/2/

The problem is its hard to have rectangular box with corners to align the triangle as above?

It is for iphone app using Hybrid coding.

UPDATE: @andyb. Thank you for the update and this is what I see as below:

[image: align top]
<sub>(source: [kerrydeaf.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140404095401/http://www.kerrydeaf.com/arrow2.png))</sub>

UPDATE: @andyb. It is now solved and a screen shot from iOS 6 stimulator.
[image: align top]
<sub>(source: [kerrydeaf.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20140404095405/http://www.kerrydeaf.com/arrow3.png))</sub>

UPDATE: Question: How do I move a yellow box down and touch the box a light blue box without leaving a gap?

[image: align top]
<sub>(source: [kerrydeaf.com](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/arrow4.png))</sub>

UPDATE: Answer: It is now solved: added this margin-bottom:-8.5px on span.trig_italic2 CSS and it worked. (Image is not included)

Comment: Good to read that this question has a solution. I think the next part should be asked as another question. When asking another question it would be very useful to reference this question so others can get some background knowledge. Regarding the update though, I would need to see more of the markup. There is no way to even guess an answer without the markup and CSS for those elements :-)

Comment: The next part is now solved. I've added this margin-bottom:-8.5px on span.trig_italic2 CSS and it worked. I wanted to do this myself as much as possible and this is a best way of learning the CSS.

Comment: Negative margins might not be the simplest way to solve this. Does the element after the `span.trig_italic2` have a margin that could be removed instead for example? I also see you went with the other answer in the end. My demo could work with other browsers, by using the different browser prefixed `linear-gradient` but the `border-box` is [more widely](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-box) supported.

Comment: You've a point made. I agree with what you're saying Andyb. The option I've chosen worked for iPhone app. This is for iPhone app. I'll try again with your solution later. So what is the best option instead of negative margins?

Comment: Without seeing the code I can only guess, but to remove a gap between boxes, the simplest approach is usually to set `margin:0` or `padding:0`. Is the `1. Setting appointments` a `<li>`? If so then the containing `<ul>` or `<ol>` might have a default margin which can be changed to `margin:0` therefore moving the blue box up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in padding that increases box size unless you set `box-sizing` to `border-box`.

I would do this: http://jsfiddle.net/zQKhb/9/

Comment: Thank you Andrey, it worked on iphone iOS 6 and iOS 6 stimulator. Padding creates problem separately in iPhone but the rest is ok. A border box does the trick.

Comment: Another thing about my approach is to avoid as many magic numbers as possible. The only hardcoded value is `36px` that is the height of the box. Width is set automatically to the size of contents because of `display:inline-block` and the triangle is positioned with `left: 100%; top:0` means it will always be to the right and top of the block.

Comment: That is brilliant. I've reduced the height to 30px and its look good too.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of creating a yellow triangle, how about creating a white triangle to *chop off* the end?

This does rely on making the `<span>` a bit wider, since the end will be taken up with the white triangle. So the span can be given `display:inline-block` in order for the `width` to take affect. I also had to give the height a smaller value and make the `line-height` equal to the `font-size` to keep the text vertically aligned in the middle of the block.

**Edit:** Since the background is a non-solid colour, an alternate approach would be to use a [linear-gradient](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients) to *chop off* the end. The (slight) drawback to this approach is that the start of the chopping off point is hard-coded in the CSS and will not adapt to variable width content.

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWSdA/4/) (Webkit only)

[image: result with Chrome 25 on Windows 7]

```
span.trig_italic2 {
    color:#000000;
    line-height:12px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:opensansitalic;     
    width:136px;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 12px;
    background: #FFCC05;
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    margin-right:50px;
    padding:3px 4px 3px 4px;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFCC05 100px, transparent 100px);
}
```

The original answer which works with solid colour backgrounds is left below.

[**Original demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWSdA/) (Webkit only)

```
span.trig_italic2 {
    color:#000000;
    line-height:12px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:opensansitalic;     
    width:136px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:12px;
    background: #FFCC05;
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    margin-right:50px;
    padding:3px 4px 3px 4px;
}

span.trig_italic2:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:0;
    border:12px solid transparent;
    border-color:#fff #fff transparent transparent;
}
```

​

Comment: Always a +1 for solutions that think "out of the box"

Comment: Interesting solution. I'll give it a shot. I'll revert on how I get on.

Comment: I've tried it. Look promising. How about instead of white triangle to chop off the end as transparent instead of white triangle colour and still works?
the reason for this because I've gradient background colour.

Comment: It appears transparent on ios stimulator and it appears white on iPhone app.

Comment: I wondered if the background would be non-white. So am I correct in thinking that you really need a transparent _corner_? I'll see what I can come up with :-)

Comment: I have added an updated demo which works with non-solid backgrounds, but it has it's own drawbacks in that the chop off point is a bit less variable. It's not a problem if all of your `.trig_italic2` elements have the same width.

Comment: @andyb. Thank you for the update and this is what I see a screen grab as above.

Comment: Which browser is that screenshot from? The demo only works for Webkit-based browsers. I tested against desktop Chrome and then Chrome & Safari on the iPhone. Also added a screen shot of what I see :-)

Comment: I've updated my post and it is relevant. It is to close the gap between yellow box 'before the appointments' and light blue box 'setting appointments'?